# How can I get list of all cloud SQL ( GCP ) instances which are stopped in python, I am using google cloud api for this purpose

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-sql, google-api-python-client

```
from googleapiclient import discovery

PROJECT = gcp-test-1234
sql_client = discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4')
resp = sql_client.instances().list(project=PROJECT).execute()
print(resp)
```

But in response, I am getting a state as "RUNNABLE" for stopped instances, so how can I verify that the instance is running or stopped programmatically

I have also check `gcloud sql instances describe gcp-test-1234-test-db`, it is providing state as "STOPPED"

how can I achieve this programmatically using python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Rest API, the RUNNABLE for the state field means that the instance is running, or has been stopped by the owner, as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1/instances#sqlinstancestate).

You need to read from the [activationPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1beta4/instances#sqlactivationpolicy) field, where `ALWAYS` means your instance is running and `NEVER` means it is stopped. Something like the following will work:

```
from pprint import pprint
  
from googleapiclient import discovery
service = discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4')


project = 'gcp-test-1234'


instance = 'gcp-test-1234-test-db' 
request = service.instances().get(project=project,instance=instance)
response = request.execute()

pprint(response['settings']['activationPolicy'])
```

Another option would be to use the Cloud SDK command directly from your python file:

```
import os
os.system("gcloud sql instances describe gcp-test-1234-test-db | grep state | awk {'print $2'}")
```

Or with subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("gcloud sql instances describe gcp-test-1234-test-db | grep state | awk {'print $2'}", shell=True)
```

---

Note that when you run `gcloud sql instances describe you-instance --log-http` on a stopped instance, in the response of the API, you'll see `"state": "RUNNABLE"`, however, the `gcloud` command will show the status `STOPPED`. This is because the output of the command gets the status from the activationPolicy of the API response rather than the status, if the status is `RUNNABLE`.

If you want to check the piece of code that translates the activationPolicy to the status, you can see it in the SDK. The gcloud tool is written in python:

```
cat $(gcloud info --format "value(config.paths.sdk_root)")/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/sql/instances.py|grep "class DatabaseInstancePresentation(object)" -A 17
```

You'll se the following:

```python
class DatabaseInstancePresentation(object):
  """Represents a DatabaseInstance message that is modified for user visibility."""

  def __init__(self, orig):
    for field in orig.all_fields():
      if field.name == 'state':
        if orig.settings and orig.settings.activationPolicy == messages.Settings.ActivationPolicyValueValuesEnum.NEVER:
          self.state = 'STOPPED'
        else:
          self.state = orig.state
      else:
        value = getattr(orig, field.name)
        if value is not None and not (isinstance(value, list) and not value):
          if field.name in ['currentDiskSize', 'maxDiskSize']:
            setattr(self, field.name, six.text_type(value))
          else:
            setattr(self, field.name, value)
```

Comment: Thanks  jofre and xBurnsed for the information and such a nice Explanation